# how to check online and offline status of esp8266 which is connected to firebase

Tags: android, c, firebase

I want to check if the esp8266 is currently connected to the firebase real time databases such as device is online or offline in an android app

Answer (score 0):

The https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino library is built on top of Firebase's REST API, which for the most part is connectionless (and thus won't have the concept of connection state).

The most promising I found is this [example of streaming from the database](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/tree/master/examples/FirebaseStream_ESP8266), which use the SSE part of the REST API and has a promising `if (Firebase.available()) ...` call [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/blob/master/examples/FirebaseStream_ESP8266/FirebaseStream_ESP8266.ino#L60).

Comment: sorry Frank van Puffelen i want to show the updates on my android app if (Firebase.available()) ... this code snippet only checks that the controller is connected to the database without any error it does not give any connection updates to the database